# VML RoundReact overlap on the text

Tags: html, html-email, newsletter, vml, round-rect

appreciate your help and time.

I have this issue when using VML RoundRect in email design. I refer the following code from Bulletproof email buttons. However when i set absolute position on the RoundRect, it overlay on the white text.

```html
<!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" class="email-container">

  <!-- Banner : BEGIN -->
  <tr>
    <td background="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/edgedigital/tenderloin-banner-v2.jpg" bgcolor="#ffdda4" width="600" height="280" valign="top" style="background-position: center center !important;">
      <!--[if mso]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px; height:280px; background-position: center center !important;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/edgedigital/footer-email.png"/>
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
      <![endif]-->
      <div>
        <!--[if mso]>
           <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" width="700">
               <tr>
                 <td align="right" valign="middle" width="700">
        <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" width="100%" style="margin: auto;">

          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">

              <table style="margin-right: 0!important">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" align="right" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px;">

                    <div>
         <!--[if mso]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://litmus.com" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#EB7035" fillcolor="#EB7035">
            <w:anchorlock/>
            <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">I am a button &rarr;</center>
            </v:roundrect>
         <![endif]-->
         <a href="http://buttons.cm" style="background-color:#EB7035;border:1px solid #EB7035;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">I am a button &rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <!--[if mso]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
      </div>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- BANNER : END -->
```

The normal email clients are working fine but when come to Outlook, it happened like image below shown.

[image: Outlook output result screenshot]

[image: My Ideal Goal]

As you can see, the RoundRect(orange object) is overlapping on the white display word. Please ignore the background-image at the behind. it is not related with question at all.

Please Help. Thank you again.

Comment: These VML objects cannot be nested.

Answer (score 0):

> Updating answer with a better way to do email.

Now that I have your code, I am able to give you a complete fix. Below is the code you require to solve your issued. I have removed the second VML that was causing the problem and added in a button that will work across all email clients the same way. The only thing is Outlook will not show the 3px rounded edges.

```html
 <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" class="email-container">

  <!-- Banner : BEGIN -->
  <tr>
    <td background="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/edgedigital/tenderloin-banner-v2.jpg" bgcolor="#ffdda4" width="600" height="280" valign="top" style="background-position: center center !important;">
      <!--[if mso]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px; height:280px; background-position: center center !important;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/edgedigital/footer-email.png"/>
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
      <![endif]-->
      <div>
        <!--[if mso]>
           <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" width="700">
               <tr>
                 <td align="right" valign="middle" width="700">
        <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" width="100%" style="margin: auto;">

          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">

              <table style="margin-right: 0!important">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" align="right" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px;">

       
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 100% !important;" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 15px;" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #EB7035; border-radius: 3px; text-align: center;" valign="top" bgcolor="#EB7035" align="center"> <a href="" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #EB7035; border: solid 1px #EB7035; border-radius: 3px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; padding: 12px 22px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #EB7035;">Take action now</a> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
       
       
                    
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <!--[if mso]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
      </div>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- BANNER : END -->
```

You can add more tables around the button to space it out properly and control it using CSS and media queries on supported devices.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Syfer, Thanks for fast replying my question.

No, you misunderstanding the question. What i trying to say is the roundrect (orange subject) supposely as a background of the white text. However, as you can see the roundrect was overlapping on the white text which i headache now. 

Please ignore the background-image at the behind. it is not related with question at all.

Please help again, Thanks.

Comment: your code is not what it is from the image you loaded. Cant do much if I cant see what i am trying to fix?

Comment: Syfer, i have already edit the question. Now it should be clearer for the question. As you can see, i have a background image and inside the background image i have another bulletproof button. But the bulletproof button orange subject was overlap to the text. I did tried remove the background image, and surprising the button is fine. It seem the background cause the issue. Do you have any clue on it?

Comment: VML inside a vml will not work. I will let you know in a few hours how to fix it if someone doesn't before me.

Comment: You cannot nest VML objects like your code is. It will ALWAYS break. Trust me, I found this out the hard way.

Comment: @Syfer the only thing to do is rely on the `background` in CSS and if it breaks, it breaks.

Comment: @scoopzilla i have updated my answer above which i think will solve the issue. You get the button, the background image and functionality as per requirement (with disclaimer for outlook).

Comment: Hi Syfer, thanks ur great answer. I've found the issue and fix it already in last couple of days But i greatly thanks for your contribute. I will look into your code and learn from it. Thank again.

Comment: Add what you found to be an issue as an answer so everyone facing it can fix it if they face it.

Comment: It actually similar to what you describe up there. No nest VML object which will always break.